# Legal aspects of virtual machines

Tags: testing, windows-xp, virtualization

My normal pc is currently under 'repair' due to me uninstalling a bunch of apps in an attempt to fix an old app that failed in certain situations and causing a looping screen of blue death.

Now I've been asking for the ability to have virtual machines so I can do testing of legacy software in a safe and controlled manner and not worry about currently installed apps/services hiding the symptoms since I joined here and this incident is ammo for my cause.

However I get shot down saying that I would need a license of XP for every copy I have installed on my machine.  I think this is wrong (Scott Hanselman freely admits to using multiple Win7 installs - or is this just a Win7 license thing?) but have no evidence to back up my claims.

**What is the legalities of running virtual machines - XP in particular - for the purpose of testing?**

Comment: You might get a good answer for this on the SO SuperUser site which covers hardware and the like.

Comment: I reckon it's a server fault question, I'd expect those guys to be the virtualization experts :)

Comment: But it isn't really SU content. The virtualization is trying to recreate environment for testing and detecting problems - something close to a developers heart!

Comment: Again, it isn't really SF content. The virtualization is trying to recreate environment for testing and detecting problems - something close to a developers heart!

Comment: SuperUser, ServerFault, Meta - so many sites so little time!

Comment: Yeah but how many non-developers know anything about licensing for dev/test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can get VM's on the Microsoft site which have XP and IE on them (the operating system often 'expires' after a few weeks/months) I guess that covers the legalities.

These [VPC images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) are designed for testing and expire on 1 July 2010 - there can be no issue using them.

> **Overview**
>
> This download page contains
> different VPC images, depending on
> what you want to test.
>
> IE6-on-XP-SP3.exe contains a Windows
> XP SP3 with IE6 VHD file. Expires July
> 1, 2010
>
> IE7-on-XP-SP3.exe contains a Windows
> XP SP3 with IE7 VHD file. Expires July
> 1, 2010
>
> IE8-on-XP-SP3.exe contains a Windows
> XP SP3 with IE8 VHD file. Expires July
> 1, 2010
>
> IE7-VIS1.exe+IE7-VIS2.rar+IE7-VIS3.rar
> contain a Vista Image with IE7 VHD
> file. Expires 120 days after first
> run.
>
> IE8-VIS1.exe+IE8-VIS2.rar+IE8-VIS3.rar+IE8-VIS4.rar
> contain a Vista Image with IE8 VHD
> file. Expires 120 days after first
> run.
>
> Note: For The Vista image, you will
> need files in that set, downloaded and
> in the same directory, then run the
> EXE in the root directory.

Comment: Can you do anything to them - they don't reset after shutting them down or something?

Comment: No I've used them for testing without probs.  The VPC itself is not cobbled - just the OS software that 'expires' (ie requests proper license registration on a certain date).  I've put a similarly time limited 'evaluation' copy of Visual Studio on a similar setup for running on someone else's computer so I didn't mess up their settings on a contract.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase a [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com) subscription, you get (nearly unlimited) licenses of almost all Microsoft applications and operating systems for **testing and development (i.e. non-Production) use only**. You just log in to the website, click a button labeled "get license" each time you need another license for a new VM.

There's an expensive subscription (which includes Visual Studio licenses) for developers, and the cheaper version which we use for each member in the test/support/QA teams.

Note that while you have access to plenty of licenses, according to the Microsoft rep I spoke with   each person that accesses or uses the installed software is also required to have a technet subscription.